# P thread Create Pointer issue

Tags: c, multithreading, pointers, struct, pthreads

```
   #include <stdio.h>
   #include <stdlib.h>
   // Thread Declarations
  #include <pthread.h>
 pthread_t monitor_thread;
 void *Get_Monitor_Data(void *BM_params);


// this is my struct ///

typedef struct
{
HCORE BM_cores[0];
int total_cores;
} BM_PARAMS;

BM_PARAMS BM_Dat;

int Start_monitor(void)
{
int RETVAL=0;
 RETVAL = pthread_create(&monitor_thread, NULL, Get_Monitor_Data,(void*)BM_Dat);
 if(RETVAL !=0)
{
 printf("Error Starting Thread \n");
}

return 0;
}
void *Get_Monitor_Data (void *BM_Dat) // Bus Monitor Thread
{
BM_PARAMS*monitor_params;
int no_of_cores=0;
monitor_params = (BM_PARAMS *) BM_Dat;

BTICard_CardReset(*monitor_params->BM_cores);// reset card if required

return 0;
}
```

The pthread create portion is giving error of "cannot convert to a pointer type"
is there anything wrong which i am doing?
i need to pass a structure to the P thread function as argument, how can i do that?

Comment: What is `monitor_thread`? You also claim that you have "declared Get_Monitor_Data before my main" which is not shown the in the post. Please provide complete and exact code as a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) as well as the exact and complete error message.

Comment: It needs to be `&BM_Dat` as last parameter to `pthread_create`

Comment: I tried changing to &BM_Dat  at that time Eclipse don't recognize my functions in include file

Comment: G:\Projects\Eclipse Resources\BM Ballard\BM_BALLARD\Debug/..\BallardBM/BM_BALLARD.c:46: undefined reference to `BTICard_CardOpen'
G:\Projects\Eclipse Resources\BM Ballard\BM_BALLARD\Debug/..\BallardBM/BM_BALLARD.c:60: undefined reference to `BTICard_CoreOpen'
G:\Projects\Eclipse Resources\BM Ballard\BM_BALLARD\Debug/..\BallardBM/BM_BALLARD.c:64: undefined reference to `BTI1553_ChIs1553'

Comment: That's a totally different issue. Post a new question.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to cast `BM_Dat` which has structure type to a `void *`.  A `struct` cannot be converted to a pointer.  You can however pass the address of `BM_Dat`:

```
RETVAL = pthread_create(&monitor_thread, NULL, Get_Monitor_Data, &BM_Dat);
```

A `BM_PARAMS *` can be converted to a `void *` (implicitly in fact), and in fact your thread function converts the parameter to this type.

Comment: I have declared Get_Monitor_Data before my mains void *Get_Bus_Monitor_Data(void *BM_Dat);

Comment: Im getting Error At Pthread Create "(void*)BM_Dat" it says Cannot Convert To a Pointer Type

Comment: Give a complet minimal and compilable example showing your error.

Comment: Code is not Compiling im getting Error Cannot Convert To a Pointer Type  at create P thread

Comment: this is the console report ---

Comment: .\BallardBM\BM_BALLARD.c: In function 'Start_monitor':
..\BallardBM\BM_BALLARD.c:83:2: error: cannot convert to a pointer type
  RETVAL = pthread_create(&monitor_thread, NULL, Get_Monitor_Data,(void*)BM_Dat);
  ^